# MS Access FE to SQL Server BE, can't add new Record to a table via ADODB

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, adodb, sql-timestamp

I'm in the process of migrating to SQL Server for my BE away from MS Access.

Before we start I have checked and double checked the PK is ok.  There is 2 x 'Bit' fields but both are set to ((0)) with NO NULL set. I believe this is a 'SSMA_timeStamp issue'.

I have a table in SQL Server  called `tbl_WorkOrders` and I want to add a new record to it (this has worked for almost 15 years).    User presses 'Add New' on a form and following code code runs then a new form opens to the new record and user enters details.

```
Function funCreateNewWO() As Long

Dim adoRst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlString As String

    Set adoConn = CurrentProject.Connection
    sqlString = " SELECT [WO_ID_PK] FROM tbl_WorkOrders"
   
    With adoRst
        .Open sqlString, adoConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
        If .State = adStateOpen Then
            .AddNew
            .Update
            funCreateNewWO = !WO_ID_PK
        End If
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Now when I run with SQL BE and execute the .Update line I get

> "ODBC-- call fail"

As a test I

1. Created a view `sv_WorkOrders` in SQL on `tbl_WorkOrders` and removed the 'SSMA_timeStamp' field
2. Created a linked table in MS Access to `sv_WorkOrders`
3. Ran above code substituting `tbl_WorkOrders` for `sv_WorkOrders`

It all worked fine.  So I thought 'HaHa I've found you'.   So I read up more on TimeStamps and I was convinced to leave them in and work with them.

So I ran above code with a few changes allowing for `SSMA_timeStamp`

```
If .State = adStateOpen Then
   .AddNew
   !SSMA_timeStamp = Now()
   .Update
   funCreateNewWO = !WO_ID_PK
End If
```

Now when I execute `!SSMA_timeStamp = Now()` I get the following error.

> "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

What can I try next? I've been reading about the above error and there are suggestions that it may be text field errors but at this stage text fields have not been altered.

### Update

I have tested using DAO and I'm still getting errors but the errors codes are more interesting.

```
Function funTestDAO()

    Dim myRST As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sqlString As String
    Dim lTest As Long

    sqlString = "tbl_WorkOrders"
    Set myRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlString, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    With myRST
         If .EOF = False Then
            .AddNew
            .Update
            lTest = !WO_ID_PK
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Then I get the following errors when I execute the `.Update` line I get the ODBC--call failed

> 544          [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl_WorkOrders' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.    ODBC.Recordset

Comment: *"... a new form opens to the new record  ..."*  If that's what you want, why not just open the new form and then [DoCmd.GoToRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.gotorecord) to the new record (`acNewRec`)?

Comment: Using identity field for primary key?

Comment: @HansUp All existing code is based 'ADOdb' i dont want to go away from this.

Comment: Are you using timestamp datatype for the column? The name is unfortunate because timestamp has absolutely nothing to do with dates or times. Its purpose is solely to detect concurrent changes in the record. It is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @June7 Yes,  Identity Specification = YES, (Is Identity) = YES, Increment =1, Seed = 1

Comment: @Galaxiom Thanks, im bit confused about Deprecated?  I only migrated yesterday using MS MMSA for Access and it added the 'MMSA_timeStamp' field at end of each table.  But is appears that i cant ignore it or use 'Views" on all tables?

Comment: I have links set to SQLServer Express tables on my laptop. I cannot get ADODB recordset to work. I use DAO. My tables have timestamp field, had problems if didn't.

Comment: Apparently, it's because my links are based on ODBC. Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-access-to-sql-server-050d88f3-b2d6-4e76-b6f9-f3c556f139ea#:~:text=Use%20an%20ODBC%20connection%20string%20for%20DAO.%20Use,and%20supports%20for%20both%20ODBC%20and%20OLEDB%20respectively.

Comment: You do not populate SQLServer timestamp type field by code or data entry. This is a field managed by SQLServer and does not receive data. In Access the field will appear empty. Ignore it.

Comment: @June7 thats the problem i cant seem to ignore it.  Only when i clone the table via Views in SQL can i add a record.   Im thinking its an ADOdb thing,  i thought that was the whole idea of ADOdb,  flexibility with data sources

Comment: I also don't understand why you use recordset to add a new record in table then open form as opposed to simply opening a form to new record row and populating the foreign key field via form. I don't understand why recordset approach would have been implemented 15 years ago. Why not use form/subform arrangement?

Comment: Yes, ADODB can work with variety of data sources but have to get the connection syntax correct, hence the link I posted earlier. If you establish link with ODBC then as I understand it, use DAO recordset. I only experimented with SQLServer on my laptop, not really a production database and didn't use OLEDB connection.

Comment: i have tried a few other things. how do update this.  Do i just edit my original post or is there away to insert a new post into this one?

Comment: @June7  Usually my DBs the forms are only 10 to 20% of it.  I do loads calculations which are form independent, for this i have always use ADO.

Comment: Can edit question or delete. I see you have already started another question for basically the same issue. Did you review the article I linked in earlier comment?

Comment: @June7 yes i actually read that last night.  It said said try not to mix technologys.  That is why i stay with ADO.  i find its better for harder data analysis.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know which method you used to connect to SQLServer: ODBC or OLEDB.

Comment: Can you add a row manually to the linked table when it is open in Access' Datasheet View?

Comment: @HansUp Yes i can manually add.  Also when i clone the the table in SQL via a View i can add that way as well.

Comment: Of course we will have over the years a reocrdset that adds a new row. often code behind does that, and should be free to do so. The idea that ONLY forms can add new records? Nope - not even close to a supportable narrative here. See my post below, I explain what is going on, and how you have to deal with this issue when using SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first up:

The so called "timestamp" column has NOTHING but I repeat NOTHING to do with "time". That column is what we call a "row version". If you are wondering, behind the scenes that "row version" column is actually a double int column, and it simply increments by +1 each time that row is updated.

To be fair, calling that column type "timestamp" is the world's worst name in the history of databases, since such row version columns are not a time-based column. Such row version columns are managed by the database system, and you NEVER I repeat NEVER will touch, modify, look at, or care about this column. Most systems such as .net or MS-Access? They can and will use this "row version" technology to determine if the record been updated. This eliminates the need for the client software to do a column by column compare to the loaded record against the server record to detect if changes have been made.

You the developer don't care, nor never will attempt to look at, use or bother with these so-called row version columns. To be fair, in the last few years, you will see on Microsoft documentation they now use the term “row version” and not the term “timestamp”. However, there is “years” of documentation that has their older term “timestamp”.

While in the SSMS table designer, the option still appears as “timestamp”, it is still what we call a row version data type of a column, and as noted, it actually is simple long integer value that increment by +1 each time the row is updated. Such a column is not time based, and does not even store a date/time value.

This row version column as noted is used by client software to detect if the record been changed.

Next up:

If you using a SQL insert statement, then all columns will automatically take on their assigned default value specified in that SQL server table.

However, if you using a DAO, or ADO record insert command? Then those columns DO NOT take on the default column settings. So, if you add a new record by a linked table (in a form), then the SQL server default column values are used.

If you use DAO/ADO and a SQL insert statement, then again, the SQL server default values are automatic set when the new row is created.

HOWEVER!
if you use the .new row method of a reocrdset? Then the SQL server default values are NOT used.

So, if I have this simple table in SQL server:

[image]

Now how in above, I don't allow nulls for my 2 true/false (bit) columns in above.

Thus, if adding by using a form, or SQL insert statements? Then those 2 example bit columns will take on the default value setting I have (of 0 in this case).

However, if I use ado/dao and new row? Then you have to in code set the default value(s). You could I suppose remove the default values in the SQL table, but either way, the simple issue is that default values are not set by DAO/ADO when using new row method of a reocrdset object.

So, the required code for above then becomes this:

```
Sub TestADOAddRow()

   Dim rst          As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim adoCon       As ADODB.Connection
   Dim sqlString    As String
   
   Dim lngNewPK     As Long
   
   
   Set adoCon = CurrentProject.Connection
   
   sqlString = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsD"
   
   With rst
      .Open sqlString, adoCon, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
      .AddNew
      !Active = True
      !HasBalcony = True
      .Update
       lngNewPK = rst!ID
      .Close
   End With
   
   Debug.Print "New pk = " & lngNewPK
   
End Sub
```

So, note how I had/have to set the 2 columns default. I could of course eliminate the need to set "Active" and "HasBalcony" to false if I remove the restriction in the table to not allow nulls. But, as pointed out, often null bits will confuse Access. In most cases, you can get away with null bits, but it is MUCH better to set the defaults to 0 (or 1) at row create time.

I will note and point out this same issue exists when using .net and datatable(s), since they again also when using the .new row method of the data table object don't obtain nor get/grab the defined defaults you setup in SQL server.

So, as noted, there are 2 work arounds:

Use a real SQL server insert statement (but, this for reocrdsets of course is painfull).

Or, upon .AddNew, then set the defaults for ANY column that is not allowed nulls, and thus requires a default value.